# Hosting python model on Tableau server - ConnectionError

Tags: python-3.x, tableau-api, tabpy

I've created a regression model in Python and trying to host the model on Tableau.. I'm using this article as reference: [Link](https://www.tableau.com/developer/learning/bring-your-own-machine-learning-models-tableau-analytics-extensions-api)

This is what I tried:

De-pickle model:

```
rf_reg = pickle.load(open('CostEngine.pkl','rb'))
```

Try to host locally first:

```
client = Client('http://localhost:9004/')

client.deploy('Cost Engine',
rf_reg,
'Cost Engine returns logistics costs.'
, override = True)
```

However I'm getting this error: `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('ÿ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x7f'))`